# Is there a module that lets one person do a bulk publish/update?

Tags: 7, nodes

On my site I need the ability to let multiple people edit and add content, but I need that content to be only able to be published at one time by one person.

Is there a module out there that lets a user of a certain role publish all of the new and updated content at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible using the [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module (=VBO) ... Quote from its project page:

> ... augments [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) by allowing bulk operations to be executed on the displayed rows. It does so by showing a checkbox in front of each node, and adding a select box containing operations that can be applied. Drupal Core or Rules actions can be used.

So create a view that lists all "content waiting to be published", whereas you might want to limit the access to such view to only that "one person" (the content approver?).

Then have the content approver use VBO to select "all" content to then apply "bulk operation" = "publish".

Should you want to do so, you could further enhance/refine this content approval process with modules [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) and [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) modules also. Refer to these questions to get an idea of the possibilities:

- [How can I allow anonymous visitors to submit content?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164199/content-submission-by-anonymous-users/164226#164226).
- [How to implement a nomination process for nodes?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/157714/how-to-implement-a-nomination-process-for-nodes)

Comment: Thanks for the "accept"! And possibly upvote also? Let me know if you're interested in more details about how to further refine/enhance this answer related to the flag/Rules module. By the way, just upvoted your question also (forgot to do so before). And by doing so, I believe you now also got enough "reputation" to start upvoting ...

Comment: I am very interested in more details about how to further refine/enhance the answer using the flag/Rules module!

Yeah, thanks for the upvote! 
It let me upvote your answer!